# "nohup" with a bash script - will programs called from the bash script be interrupted?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, python

For my work setup, I'm currently ssh'ing into a remote machine. I want to call a certain python program several times with different arguments, so I wrote a simple bash script that looks like this:

get_results.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
python generate.py -d 10
python generate.py -d 20
...
```

My question is, if I run this bash script as `nohup ./get_results.sh`, then I disconnect from the ssh connection, will all the python programs execute normally?

Comment: ```` nohup ./get_results.sh &  add ampersand at end

Answer (score 1):

I've since tried this, and it does execute all of the python programs as expected.

The "nohup" command does *not* need to be included inside the bash script (in front of "python ...".